# Make a window stay on top and be only active window using QT/C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am on RHEL 6 and am creating an app using C++ and QT.  I am trying to make my window/app be on top and be the only app the user can interact with.

I have set: 
  setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);

But the user can still click on a different app, which then comes to the top.  I need to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by adding "show();" after I set the windowFlags.